# PowerShell variables aren't passing to Invoke-Command

Tags: windows, powershell, pagefile

I'm putting a small script together to allow my team to update the page file min/max size and place the page file on a drive other than the system drive. If I run this script on the server with static values, it works just fine;

```
$ComputerSystem = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem
$ComputerSystem.AutomaticManagedPagefile = $false
$ComputerSystem.Put()

#Remove all pagefiles
$pf = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_PageFileSetting
$pf.delete()

#Do the work
Set-WmiInstance -Class Win32_PageFileSetting -Arguments @{name="P:\pagefile.sys";InitialSize = 0; MaximumSize = 0} -EnableAllPrivileges
$SetPF = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_PageFileSetting | where{$_.caption -like 'P:*'}
$SetPF.InitialSize = 16
$SetPF.MaximumSize = 12288
$SetPF.Put()
```

So, I created a script to run against remote system using the Invoke-Command. When I run the Invoke the required drive letter is passed into the cmd and places the page file on that drive. But when it reaches the point where the min/max sizes are specified, it bonks. Here's the script;

```
#Get Page File Size and Path
    $MinSize= Read-Host "Enter minimum size in MB"
    $MaxSize = Read-Host "Enter maximum size in MB"
    $GetDrive = Read-Host "What drive do you want the Page File to exist"
    $PagePath = $GetDrive + ":\pagefile.sys"


#Do the work
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PFServer -ScriptBlock{Set-WmiInstance -Class Win32_PageFileSetting -Arguments @{name= $using:PagePath;InitialSize = 0; MaximumSize = 0} -EnableAllPrivileges; 
    $SetPF = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_PageFileSetting | where{$_.caption -like $Using:GetDrive};
    $SetPF.InitialSize = $Using:MinSize;
    $SetPF.MaximumSize = $Using:MaxSize;
    $SetPF.Put()}
```

Here is the error:

```
The property 'InitialSize' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : Server01

The property 'MaximumSize' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : Server01

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
    + PSComputerName        : Server01
```

I'm a little confused. I've tried a million (it seems) ways to make this work, but so far no dice. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try replacing the ; with a , to separate the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying that `$SetPF` is blank, so check whether the `Get-WmiObject` command actually returned anything. You can also test like:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PFServer -ScriptBlock {
  "using these values remotely:", $using:MinSize, $using:MaxSize, $using:GetDrive

  $SetPF = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_PageFileSetting | where{$_.caption -like $Using:GetDrive}
  "current settings are:", $SetPF
}
```

`Win32_PageFileSetting` is blank on systems where the page file is still managed by the OS. Double-check whether the `Set-WmiInstance` actually succeeded in creating one, or check if `(gwmi Win32_ComputerSystem).AutomaticManagedPagefile` still returns `True`

Comment: Hey, CPt.Whale.

I just tried your suggestion and the min/max values are returning, but the WMIObject is not. I call the WMIObject later in the script and it appears using a different var name. So... I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Also, the page file does get created on whatever drive I specify in the script. It just gets set to system managed because the min/max vars aren't applying.

Comment: Ah yep, in your local example, you filter on `$_.caption -like 'P:*'`, but in the remote script, you are using `$GetDrive` with no wildcard `*`, so there are probably no matches

Comment: I'm wondering if there is some permissions issue with setting the min/max size. The error states "Verify that the property exists and can be set." Even though I'm running my PS session with the same user account that has local admin on that remote server, should I maybe have to specify my user account again somehow? Or run the remote system as elevated (again -- somehow)?

Comment: @Dale, did you see the previous comment? What happens if you get the wmi setting without the `where` command? And probably not - remote PS sessions run as admin by default, and there are very few things that you can't access (mostly stuff like double-hopping to a third device).

Comment: Sorry, no I didn't see that. I removed the Where clause and it seems to be working. Now I need to understand why it's working...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dale What's an example of a valid `caption` value? (I don't have one to test with). It would probably work if you used `where{$_.caption -like "$($Using:GetDrive):*"}` with the `:*` which is missing from your static values example

Comment: I think I had a wildcard in there before and the Where ended up being an artifact. To be honest I'm not sure. I have been bashing my head on the keyboard for a few days trying to get this to work.